# Ubuntu 22.04 with horizontal tear on MSI z16

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, 22.04, screen

I've been getting this on my MSI z16 and I wonder if anyone else have and if so, how they went about solving it. The weird thing about this tear is that it water-reflects the graphics. What you're seeing is that I'm on Google Colab but now it's reflecting the top of that page upsidedown.

I have Nvidia 535.54.03 with CUDA 12.2

[image]